# How to change the background of table cell based on the text/values?

Tags: javascript

I have made a simulator in a servlet that reads a text file and inserts data in mysql. Also I have displayed that data in one jsp page. Now I want to set the background color of the table based on severity; like if severity is critical then background color must be red, if it is warning then it should be yellow. How can I do this thing?

```
<script language="javascript">

var tbl = document.getElementById("table1_id");
var c = "critical";
var maj = "major";

// alert(tbl.rows[4].cells.length);
if (tbl != null) {
    for (var i = 1; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
            if (j == 2) {
                var tmp = tbl.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
                alert(typeof(tmp) + " and " + typeof(maj));
                var tmp = "major";
                alert("value of severity" + tmp);
                if (tmp == maj) {
                    alert("hi-- I am major");
                } else alert("its not working");
            }
        }
    }
} else document.writeln("Sorry");

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your problem and based on my understanding I've created a fiddle to help you solve your problem.

Here is the code, assuming your jsp will render an html with a table having some number of rows and columns. One of the column will be the severity column with values "Critical" and "Major". You want the "Critical" values to be background red and "Major" values to be yellow. So here we go-

```
tmp=tbl.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
switch(tmp) {
    case critical:
        tbl.rows[i].cells[2].className='red-background';
        break;
    case major:
        tbl.rows[i].cells[2].className='yellow-background';
        break;    
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/a2TvF/)**

Appreciate.

Comment: still there is prob :(

Comment: plz help me as early as possible

Comment: Where is the problem?